# Can "WHERE" be omitted in the following SQL statement?

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am trying to dynamically build query that should look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM candidate_info 
INNER JOIN candidate_job ON info_uniqid = job_info_uniqid 
INNER JOIN candidate_status ON info_uniqid = status_info_uniqid 
WHERE 1 = 1
AND status_status = :status_status
```

Accidentally I discovered that if I omit the `WHERE` clause the query works just fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM candidate_info 
INNER JOIN candidate_job ON info_uniqid = job_info_uniqid 
INNER JOIN candidate_status ON info_uniqid = status_info_uniqid 
AND status_status = :status_status
```

Can you please help me understand:

1. Why is the query still working?
2. What are the risks of using the query without the `WHERE` clause?

Note: `WHERE 1 = 1` is chosen for its simplicity.

Thank you very much!

Comment: "Chosen for simplicity" ?? Who chose it? Why did they choose it?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add a tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is working because you have moved the condition from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause.

Because you are working with `INNER JOIN`, the effect is exactly the same.  The two queries do the same thing and should have the same execution plan.

I would suggest that you qualify your column names, so it is clear what table they come from.  I am guessing the column comes from `candidate_status`.  If so, putting it in the `on` clause is more a question of style.

Comment: What I am actually trying to do is to join three tables based on a common id and then fetch data based on what status the user is selecting from a drop-down menu. Your answer helped me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add more then one condition to `JOIN ON`, so that is what you are doing. You

```
INNER JOIN candidate_status ON
(
  info_uniqid = status_info_uniqid AND status_status = :status_status
)
```